# Ajax update does not work

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

Why is the `#{uImanager.select}` never updated?

```
<p:panel id="EditDetailsPanel" header="Edit Details">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
        <h:outputLabel value="Simple :" />
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{uImanager.select}">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="val1" itemLabel="Coffee1" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="val2" itemLabel="Coffee2" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="val3" itemLabel="Coffee3" />                                  
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="EditDetailsForm:EditDetailsPanel"/>
    #{uImanager.select}
</p:panel>
```

It points to a `private String Select;` with a getter and setter. It's defined in a session scoped managed bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `update` attribute likely points to an invalid client ID. If you paid attention to the server logs, then you should have seen something like the following from PrimeFaces:

```
INFO: Cannot find component with identifier "EditDetailsForm:EditDetailsPanel" in view.
```

As the `<p:panel>` is inside the same [`UINamingContainer`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UINamingContainer.html) parent as the `<p:commandButton>` itself (at least, based on the code which you've posted so far), you can just specify its relative client ID:

```html
<p:commandButton value="Submit" update="EditDetailsPanel"/>
```

Or if you insist in specifying the absolute client ID, then you need to prefix it with `:`:

```html
<p:commandButton value="Submit" update=":EditDetailsForm:EditDetailsPanel"/>
```

Note that this only works if the `<h:form>` does by itself not have another [`UINamingContainer`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UINamingContainer.html) parent. Open the page in browser, rightclick and *View Source* to figure the generated HTML element ID. Finally you need to take that value, prefixed with `:`.

Comment: This is not problem.this code is in a form with id="EditDetailsForm"

Comment: This shouldn't matter. Relative client IDs are resolved to current `UINamingContainer` parent. If you really insist in specifying lengthy and absolute client IDs, then you have need to prefix it with `:`. But I don't see how that's useful. Just use the value as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I've changed update to EditDetailsPanel and also to :EditDetailsForm:EditDetailsPanel but no chance.there is no UINamingContainer in parrent

Comment: Solved. this code is in <c:if test="${param.subpage == 'EditDetails'}"> I add <f:param name="subpage" value="EditDetails"/>  to commandButton and it's working now

Comment: Okay. In the future don't leave this detail out of the question.